# How to resize WPF About Box

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have trying to use that about bopx in my WPF application http://www.nuget.org/packages/AboutBox/
but i cant figure out how to resize it and how to make it not dragable. I tried that but no way:

```
            About about = new About();
            about.Window.Width = 120;
            about.Window.Height = 130;
            about.Window.MaxWidth = 120;
            about.Window.MaxHeight = 130;
            about.Window.MinWidth = 120;
            about.Window.MinHeight = 130;
            about.Window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            about.Window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
            about.Window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            about.Window.AllowDrop = false;
            about.Show();
```

May be some one may help.
Also I would like to display close or OK button to close the window, and want to disable closing window when focus is loosing.

**UPDATE:**
I ended up by using http://wpfmbx.codeplex.com/ it is exactly what i need

Comment: http://aboutbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/About_net40/AboutControlView.xaml

Comment: If you don't need all those features for a `About Box`, why use it? Just create a standard `Window` for yourself

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried that About box but following should be the correct order for heights:

```
        About about = new About();
        about.Window.MinWidth = 120;
        about.Window.MinHeight = 130;
        about.Window.MaxWidth = 120;
        about.Window.MaxHeight = 130;
        about.Window.Width = 120;
        about.Window.Height = 130;
```

MinWidth/MinHeight takes precedence then comes MaxWidth/MaxHeight and Width/Height. I am not 100 % sure that it is the cause of your problem, just give it a try.

To be able to make it drag-able manually, then you just need to call DragMove(), on MouseDown or some similar event.